# spring data specification and postgres function that returns set

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

say I have a classic db structure with employee and departments (each employee belongs to one department and departments form hierarchy)

```sql
create table employee(emp_id bigint, dep_id bigint)
create table department(dep_id bigint, dep_parent_id bigint)
```

my goal is to write a query using jpa specification (only) that will returns list of employees that belong to specific department (or array of such departments) or to any child department

my first take was to use custom postgres function that returns list of all departments that are child to one selected.

it's done easily with so classic recursive cte

so say i have

```
create function get_hierarchy_from_top(bigint[])
    returns TABLE(id bigint)
    language sql
as
$$
with recursive h as (select dep_id as id
                     from department where dep_id = any($1)
                     union
                     select dep_id from department
                              inner join h on h.id = department.dep_parent_id)
select *
from h;
$$;
```

from sql syntax perspective i can write only (and this works fine)

```sql
select *
from employees
inner join get_hierarchy_from_top('{"25", "26"}') f on f.id = employee.dep_id
```

but now i have absolutely no idea how i can translate this into spring/jpa specifications language

btw: i tried playing with jpa specification & where condition that checks dept_id against values returned by custom function which resulted in code sql code

```sql
select *
from employees
where employees.dept_id in (get_hierarchy_from_top('{"25"}'))
```

but this is forbidden by postgres as

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

so you see my problems:

I can write using jpa specification expression that is not working in postgres

and

I cannot write in jpa specification that makes join with result of function invocation.

Comment: have you tried to create a view with [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) and use in as read-only entity?

Answer (score 0):

well this looks as a little bit of magic but:

this sql doesn't work

```sql
select *
from employees
where dep_id in (get_hierarchy_from_top(15));
```

and this one works

```sql
select *
from employees
where dep_id in (select * from get_hierarchy_from_top(15));
```

not sure about low-levels details of such difference
but i can make jpa to render proper sql by writing

```java
predicates.add(root.get("department").get("id").in(
                    criteriaBuilder.function("select * from get_hierarchy_from_top", Long[].class, criteriaBuilder.literal(depId))
            )))
```